# Make loading accessible

Tags: accessibility

I have provided a loading gif for the dynamic app i am working on. What should a screen reader like voice over read when the page is loading(the loading sign being displayed)?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what Illias mentioned:

1. Implement a statement like "Loading [name of thing being loaded]".
2. Add an interval that repeats it every couple of seconds.
3. When it's finished, a "Loading Complete" prompt should notify the user when loading is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys but i guess i miscommunicated. So does the screen reader has a default sentence which it reads or should it be injected manually in a code...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be "Loading [app name], please hold on" or something simular.

The purpose of that loading gif is to inform the user that the app is loading and that the user shall wait until that process has been completed.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys but i guess i miscommunicated. So does the screen reader has a default sentence which it reads or should it be injected manually in a code...

Comment: HI and sorry for my late reply: There's no default sentence. Instead add the attribute aria-label="this text will be spoken" into that <img> tagg.